# Get element of known type in a list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, inheritance

I'm got a problem with derivative classes.

I have a parent class and several child classes

```
public abstract class Parent
{}

public class Child1 : Parent
{}

public class Child2 : Parent
{}

public class Child3 : Parent
{}
```

Then I have a list of those objects

```
List<Parent> myList = new List<Parent>(){ new Child1(), new Child2(), new Child2() .....};
```

I want a function to retrieve an object of this list specifying its type.  For now, I build such methods one for each child type, but when the number of children types increase, it could be a problem

```
public Child1 GetChild1()
{
  Child1 child = myList.FirstOrDefault(ch => ch is Child1) as Child1;
  if(child == null)
  {
     child = new Child1;
     myList.Add(child);
  }
  return child;
}
```

I'm looking for something like

```
public Parent GetChild(Type typeOfChild)
-- or --
public Parent GetChild(string typeOfChild)
-- or --
public Parent GetChild<T>()
```

**EDIT: First progress**

```
  private void GetChild<T>() where T : class
  {
     IEnumerable<T> list = myList.OfType<T>();
     T item;
     if(list.Count() > 0)
     {
        item= list.First<T>();
     }
     else
     {
        item= Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
     }
     myList.Add(workspace); //invalid argument
  }
```

**EDIT : Solution**

```
   private void GetChild<T>() where T : Parent, new()
   {
     T item = myList.FirstOrDefault(ch => ch is T) as T;
     if(item == null)
     {
        item = new T();
        myList.Add(item);
     }
     OtherMethod(item);
   }
```

Comment: Please don't post answers into question (self-answer is ok, also your use of reflection makes no sense when simple `new` restriction would allow the same behavior directly...)

Comment: self-answer is not yet allowed (restriction time...). Could you elaborate on your comment please ? I'm not sure to understand. Thanks !

Comment: http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+generics+new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a cleaner solution thanks to Alexei

```
private void GetChild<T>() where T : Parent, new()
{
   T item = myList.FirstOrDefault(ch => ch is T) as T;
   if(item == null)
   {
      item = new T();
      myList.Add(item);
   }
   OtherMethod(item);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use `myList.OfType<Child1>()`

`OfType<T>` filters the elements of an `IEnumerable` based on a specified type.

[Read more...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: You're plain faster! :)

Comment: ok for the first part of the question. But how to add new item to the list ? I edited my question to show.

Comment: `myList.Add(new Child1())` ?